# Django Error---'ZipCode' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python, django

i received this error while trying to update my first database evercreated in django :D I am happy about that, but i need your help with my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 571, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])
TypeError: 'ZipCode' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

This is the code i used in order to update the DB.

```
c = BusinessName(AccountingCode="0002", RefID="0001101002", FullName="Johny Cohen", Aliases="The Wolfies", Address="Florilor Street 42", City="IF", ZipCode="89899", State="Romania", Country="Romania", TypeofSanctions="SDN",Monitoring="Y", BatchNumber="1", FileName="mybeloved", UploadDate="2017-01-26", UploadBy="cohen", Decision="Noneed", Status="noneed", EngineDecision="noneed", WhoAdjudicated="cohen",DateOfAdjudication="2017-01-26", SdnType="Entity")
```

And here is my Model:

```
class BusinessName(models.Model):                                      
    AccountingCode = models.CharField(max_length=50)                   
    RefID = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")                
    FullName = models.CharField(max_length=250)                        
    Aliases = models.CharField(max_length=250)                         
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=500)                         
    City= models.CharField(max_length=50)                              
    ZipCode= models.IntegerField                                       
    State = models.CharField(max_length=250)                           
    Country= models.CharField(max_length=250)                          
    TypeOfSanction= models.CharField(max_length=250)                   
    Monitoring= models.CharField(max_length=50)                        
    BatchNumber= models.IntegerField  # tr pus automat                 
    FileName= models.CharField(max_length=250)  # tr pus automat1      
    UploadDate = models.DateField(max_length=250) # tr pus automat     
    UploadBy= models.CharField(max_length=250) # tr pus automat        
    Decision= models.CharField(max_length=250) # tr pus Ulterior       
    Status= models.CharField(max_length=250) # tr pus automat          
    EngineDecision= models.CharField(max_length=250) # tr pus automat  
    WhoAdjudicated= models.CharField(max_length=250)                   
    DateOfAdjudication= models.CharField(max_length=250)               
    SdnType = models.CharField(max_length=250)  #Entity or Individual
```

Thank you in advance,
Cohen

Answer (score 0):

You didn't instantiate the field when you declared the model, so it hasn't been recognised.

```
ZipCode= models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: thank you Daniel! now it ask me : -----You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'BatchNumber' to businessname without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py

Answer (score 0):

The line below

```
ZipCode= models.IntegerField
```

Is wrong. This should be

```
ZipCode= models.IntegerField()
```

If there is existing rows in the dB. You either have to provide a default value or provide a null= True in integer field.

```
models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
```

Comment: Thank you Arpit! i did that, but now it ask me You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'BatchNumber' to businessname without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py

Comment: You already have some data in your database so it's asking to fill some value for existing rows. You either have to provide a default or null true. See the edit

Comment: You rock! Thank you!